# Bluetooth Classic 5.1?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I bought iclever bluetooth keyboard model:IC-BK10. On amazon, it shows bluetooth logo and "5.1". I assumed it uses Bluetooth 5.1

I try to capture Bluetooth Low Energy beacon on IC-BK10. But I cannot capture any BLE packet.
I asked customer support of iclever. 
They replied 
"Please be advised that not all Bluetooth 5.1 is Bluetooth low energy. Classic Bluetooth also has Bluetooth 5.1"

Is that possible Bluetooth Classic to have 5.1 feature?

Answer (score 3):

The Bluetooth specification document (which is versioned 5.1, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, etc.) applies to both Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy. In fact, the document is a reference for the specifications of both kinds of devices. So just because a device is listed as Bluetooth version 5.1, it does not mean it’s Bluetooth Low Energy compatible.

So to answer your question: Yes, a Bluetooth 5.1 device could be Bluetooth Classic, Bluetooth Low Energy, or even both (referred to as a Dual Mode device, best example is your smartphone).

This can be a bit confusing, so always refer to the manufacturer’s technical specs  for the product or contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

The version number of Bluetooth should just be interpreted as which year's Bluetooth specification was used when the product was created or qualified. In every new version, a bunch of optional features are added and features are seldom removed.

So never look at the Bluetooth version to figure out what features a device supports. Bluetooth Classic has not been removed in newer Bluetooth versions.

A Bluetooth 2.0 product can for example usually be re-qualified for the 5.1 specification without any changes needed in the hardware or software.